# How do I solve this problem about text over image

Tags: css, image

I'm currently facing an issue regarding a Text over an image.

Here is my css code :

```
.box{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block; /* Make the width of box same as image */
    }
    .box .text{
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;        
        text-align: center;
        top: 40%; /* Adjust this value to move the positioned div up and down */
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
        width: 60%; /* Set the width of the positioned div */
    }
```

Here is my html :

```
<div class="box">
        <img src="name.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="text">
            SpinnerBait Brochet
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is how it looks like in codepen.io :

[image]

BUT, when i'm adding my html in my wordpress I have a completely different rendering.

I do have my picture where I added it in the page BUT my text is in the middle of my page (and not in the middle of my image...)

Do you have any idea what could be the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: try inspecting the page (of wordpress site) and see if `box` css is overridden by anything.

Comment: sorry to ask, but how should I know if the `box` is overridden by anything ? I have a lot of another `box` css like : `box-sizing` `border-box` `box-shadow`. Is that what you meant ?

Comment: If a css property of a class is overridden, the property will be crossed and disabled. Then you will know that this is overridden. I'm guessing your `position: relative` of `.box` class might be overridden.

Comment: The `box-sizing` is crossed and disabled. What should be the next step in order to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your question my guess is that you are trying to center the text on top of the image.

Try the following:

HTML:

```html
<div class="box">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350" alt="Placeholder">
   <div class="text">
      SpinnerBait Brochet
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.box {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
}

.box .text {
   display: inline;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
}
```

CodePen [here](https://codepen.io/ezrarieben/pen/VweJywG).

Essentially what the CSS is doing is:

1. Positioning the text absolutely in the center of it's relative container:

```
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
```

3. Changing the starting position of the X and Y axes points to the true center of the element.

```
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same issue. The Text is completely in the middle of the page and not in the middle of the image.

Comment: Could you possibly post a link to the WordPress site?

Comment: well, something weid happened. I tried again doing the same thing, and this is working properly now... unfortunately I don't know what I've done.

Comment: Possibly your browser cache or WordPress cache serving you the old css files.
Could you mark the question as solved/answered?